# How to hide only a field or query from appearing in apollo sandbox explorer

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo, apollo-server

For example, let's say I have this Query and Type in my code and I don't want it to show `_id` in Apollo sandbox explorer. Please is there a way to achieve this?

```graphql
type Query {
    getUser(userId: String!): UserObject
}

type UserObject {
    _id: String
    email: String
    firstName: String
}
```

I'm trying to make it show only `email` and `firstName` without the `_id` field in apollo sandbox explorer.

I've tried using introspection but it didn't show all my queries and mutations as expected.
I've tried using directives but I'm not getting it and I don't know how.
It should show something like this in the explorer, without the _id field.

```graphql
type Query {
    getUser(userId: String!): UserObject
}

type UserObject {
    email: String
    firstName: String
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? The GraphQL sandbox is generating the schema using an introspection query and it shows everything your schema has. I can't think of a reason to hide it only in the sandbox. If you want to remove that field completely, you can use a directive. Even in this case, the `_id` field will be removed from the schema not just from the sandbox.

Comment: It's a secret field used only in the code. For example, I need the secret field in my unit test and I don't want that field to be available for client apps to use.